# correct syntax of System.Security.Principal.NTAccount for Transfering to SecurityIdentifier

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, directoryservices, principalcontext

I want to create a **System.Security.Principal.NTAccount** object in order to transfer it for a **System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier** , so I can use it to add a new access rule to Active Directory in .Net C#

**if I use this format :**

```
  System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference newOwner new System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("DUDUG");
  newOwner.Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier);
```

I can transfer it, but then the user translates to "Unknown User" in AD

**and if I use:**

```
System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference newOwnernew System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("dudu.test.com","DUDUG")
```

or

```
System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference newOwnernew System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("//dudu.test.com/temp","DUDUG")
```

or

```
System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference newOwnernew System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("LDAP://dudu.test.com/CN=Dudu,OU=TEST,DN=DUDU,DN=TEST,DN=COM","DUDUG")
```

**i get the error message:**

```
System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException: Some or all identity references could not be translated.
```

Any ideas of how it's done?

Thanks in advance.